# Black formatter does not work in VSCode after installing anaconda3

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, formatting

settings.json

```
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/brandonwie/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",
"[python]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
},
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.formatting.blackPath": "/Users/brandonwie/opt/anaconda3/bin/black",
"python.showStartPage": false,
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
```

I'm using `VSCode`, I've installed `anaconda3` to try `conda` environment, but then `black` formatter stopped working right after I start using conda Python(I don't know it's because of conda Python). So I installed black with (conda) pip, but nothing is working..

Initially, the `blackPath` in `setting.json` was set to `/usr/local/bin/black`. The black formatter was working flawlessly until I install and set up VSCode with conda, there was a pop up at the right bottom when I saved a file "cannot find black" something like that.(because of 'format on save') I've tried changing the path to `/usr/...` and `/Users/` back and forth, but doesn't work as well.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to specify the blackpath in Settings.json.

1. Run `pip uninstall black` to delete black in current activated conda environment;
2. In Settings.json, set `"python.formatting.provider": "black",`
3. Turn to .py file then press **Ctrl+S** to save it. At the same time, there will be an notification popping up:

   [image]

   Click **Yes** and **Install using Pip**:
   [image]

After its installation, you can use black to format your file successfully.
[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton. For those of you who have the same issue, don't forget to check and delete all other formatters (i.e. autopep8, yapf) to get the pop-up message. In my case, when I uninstalled `black`, I still had `autopep8` left, so I didn't see the pop-up. However, once I uninstall all formatters it worked just as Molly explained.

Comment: This answer saved me!