# Vscode black formatter is not working in poetry project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have these settings in vscode for the `black` extension in a `poetry` project, which uses system cache and poetry venv.

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "path-to-/bin/black",
    "python.pythonPath": "path-to-/python",
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyPath": "path-to-/bin/mypy"
```

I cannot understand why the formatter formats nothing. I am using local workspace settings ( above ).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure black is installed in current used environment.

Open a integrated Terminal and activate the venv, run `pip show black` to see if it's installed in current environment. If not,

1.Comment these two settings;

> "python.formatting.provider": "black",
>
> "python.formatting.blackPath":"path-to-/bin/black",

2.Turn to python file, right click choose **Format Document With...** --> **Python**, there would be a prompt popping up to mention you install formatter, choose **install black**. After installation, the following setting will occur automatically in the Settings.json:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "black"
```

Then you can **Format Document**.

[image]

Comment: Wand thanks for this. Trying another work flow often helps see the issue from another angle. Unfortunately it did not fix my issue though.

Comment: Did you follow my steps and install black from the popping up prompt? Is there any possiblity your code already follow the rule black defined so there's no change?

Comment: Yes I already had the path there. It already has those settings yes. Mainly that the path to black exists and is where poetry installs the `bin` and that black formatter is enabled.

Comment: Don't forget to uninstall all other formatters. please have a look at this reply and try again:  [Black formatter does not work in VSCode after installing anaconda3
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800536/black-formatter-does-not-work-in-vscode-after-installing-anaconda3/65802554#65802554).

Comment: Also make sure your workspace setting for python.formatting.blackPath isn't overriding the user setting without something incorrect. And you may need to restart the black server in vscode for the setting to work

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you must set the default formatter which is language specific.
For python this is `ms-python.python` extension by Microsoft, which allows a specific formatter to be enabled, e.g autopep8, black, yapf, etc. Note I was getting notification telling me that `Extension 'prettier - Code formatter' cannot format file.py`

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
}
```

Then include your actual formatter:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackPath": "/path/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing in docker you can add

```
RUN ln -s $(poetry env info -p)/bin/black /usr/local/bin/black
```

and in your `settings.json` use the link

```
...
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/bin/black",
```

which will use your black settings in your `pyproject.toml` (i.e) something like

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 80
target-version = ['py39']
```